# Using S3 to store application configuration files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, configuration-files

I'm creating a simple web app that needs to be deployed to multiple regions in AWS.  The application requires some dynamic configuration which is managed by a separate service.  When the configuration is changed through this service, I need those changes to propagate to all web app instances across all regions.

I considered using cross-region replication with DynamoDB to do this, but I do not want to incur the added cost of running DynamoDB in every region, and the replication console.  Then the thought occurred to me of using S3 which is inherently cross-region.

Basically, the configuration service would write all configurations to S3 as static JSON files.  Each web app instance will periodically check S3 to see if the any of the config files have changed since the last check, and download the new config if necessary.  The configuration changes are not time-sensitive, so polling for changes every 5/10 mins should suffice.

Have any of you used a similar approach to manage app configurations before?  Do you think this is a smart solution, or do you have any better recommendations?

Comment: S3 is not "inherently cross-region."  Every bucket is in a specific region and requests for objects from that bucket are served from endpoints in that region only.  The `bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com` construct gives the appearance of a unified service, but that's because S3 updates its own DNS to point each bucket's subdomain to the actual correct regional endpoint.  Also, just about all services can be accessed across regions, if desired, though there are latency and data transfer charges to concern yourself with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right tool for this configuration depends on the size of the configuration and the granularity you need it.

You can use both DynamoDB and S3 from a single region to serve your application in all regions. You can read a configuration file in S3 from all the regions, and you can read the configuration records from a single DynamoDB table from all the regions. There is some latency due to the distance around the globe, but for reading configuration it shouldn't be much of an issue.

If you need the whole set of configuration every time that you are loading the configuration, it might make more sense to use S3. But if you need to read small parts of a large configuration, by different parts of your application and in different times and schedule, it makes more sense to store it in DynamoDB.

In both options, the cost of the configuration is tiny, as the cost of a text file in S3 and a few gets to that file, should be almost free. The same low cost is expected in DynamoDB as you have probably only a few KB of data and the number of reads per second is very low (5 Read capacity per second is more than enough). Even if you decide to replicate the data to all regions it will still be almost free.

Answer (score 1):

I have an application I wrote that works in exactly the manner you suggest, and it works terrific. As it was pointed out, S3 is not 'inherently cross-region', but it is inherently durable across multiple availability zones, and that combined with cross region replication should be more than sufficient.

In my case, my application is also not time-sensitive to config changes, but none-the-less besides having the app poll on a regular basis (in my case 1 once per hour or after every long-running job), I also have each application subscribed to SNS endpoints so that when the config file changes on S3, an SNS event is raised and the applications are notified that a change occurred - so in some cases the applications get the config changes right away, but if for whatever reason they are unable to process the SNS event immediately, they will 'catch up' at the top of every hour, when the server reboots and/or in the worst case by polling S3 for changes every 60 minutes.